# Getting return value for external (state changing) functions when executing safe transaction from another contract

Tags: solidity, gnosis-safe

I am using execTransaction on a 1:1 safe to make a call from a contract and would like to get the return value of that function (not just the status). I see execTransactionFromModule has an equivalent function that return data but execTransaction does not. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

No. A contract can read return values, but not a client if it is a "transaction."

Clients get return values when it's a read-only call, as in a `view` function.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is my understanding too but I am asking in the context of a gnosis-safe where it's a contract that calls execTransaction on the safe contract so there is really no client involved.